# How to prevent Recycler Adapter from populating a view based on a certain condition?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For example, as in my case, I am reading all the messages from the database and have attached a listener to database, how to make the recycler view populate only views for those messages which have currentName = "sampleName".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide access to your data in your RecyclerView.Adapter class. Then in your RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder function you'll check your data at the given position and adjust the view accordingly.

Read the [RecyclerView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). It should be pretty straight forward.